# Count highest group_id of each user as distinct value

Tags: mysql

There is a bit of tricky logic (at least for me) in my latest project and I've been trying to figure it out using `HAVING`, but all my play has incorrect results.

I have a link table that assigns users to user groups and another table that records how many users are in each group, so I don't need to keep counting them all (the second table is updated when a user registration is completed).

The thing I'm having trouble with is the function that updates the numbers in the second table.

The link table looks like this, and the sample data here explains my problem:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | group_id |
+----+---------+----------+
| 1  | 1       | 1        |
| 2  | 1       | 5        |
| 3  | 14      | 2        |
+----+---------+----------+
```

A user can be in any number of groups. In fact, in order to be one group, the user must be in all the groups below it. That's because each group has certain permissions assigned to it. This can't change without a major rewrite of the application, which is live.

What I want to do is to count each user's highest group only, so in the sample data above, user 1 will be counted only in group 5, leaving group 1 appearing to be empty.

At the moment, all entries are counted, which means if there are 3 people in group 4, those 3 users are also counted in groups 3, 2, and 1, making my numbers relatively pointless.

So far, I have tried variations on the following:

```
SELECT user_group_id, COUNT(user_id) members FROM `group_users` GROUP BY user_group_id HAVING count(user_group_id) = 1;
```

This gives me the same over-counted numbers. Then I tried:

```
SELECT user_group_id, COUNT(user_id) members FROM `group_users` GROUP BY user_group_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1;
```

But as I now understand, I'm asking only for users who do not appear in any other groups.

I feel like I am on the right track, but I can't figure out where or what the condition should be. I saw some example queries for similar processes, but all the aliases only added to the confusion.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: *Groups below it*? Does that mean *groups with larger `group_id` values than it?* Please [edit] your question to clarify, and maybe to give example data and required result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to get for each user their max `group_id` and `COUNT()` window function to count for each of the returned max `group_id`s the number of users:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(group_id) AS group_id,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MAX(group_id)) AS members
FROM group_users
GROUP BY user_id;
```

This query filters out all the `group_id`s with no memebers.

If you want results for all `group_id`s use a `LEFT` join of the table `groups` to the above query:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT MAX(group_id) AS group_id,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MAX(group_id)) AS members
  FROM group_users
  GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT g.group_id,
       COALESCE(c.members, 0) AS members
FROM `groups` AS g LEFT JOIN cte AS c
ON c.group_id = g.group_id;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/uvbLFlQk).